# Truly VS really

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

1>**Mahatma Gandhi was really a great man**

1>**Mahatma Gandhi was truly a great man**

If somebody says I have got job . we say  **really**?  but not **truly**?

we say  the question paper is **really**difficult  but not  **truly** difficult.

> **Is Mahatma Gandhi really the Father of the nation?**
>
> **Is Mahatma Gandhi truly the Father of the nation?**

we usually say the first sentence. I think it is more a matter  of  usage and  intuition.

But I feel they are almost the same but not exactly the same.

I think there is a difference between truly and really.

I have searched on the internet to find the difference and I attach the link which explains the difference.But I am not satisfied with the answers.

https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/53050#featured_answer_140434

What exactly is the difference between truly and really and how they  can be used in speech and writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top voted reply on HiNative is spot on:

1. *Really* is used much more often.
2. *Truly* is higher register.
3. *Truly* has more emphasis.

I have two more to add to this:

4. *Truly* sounds more heartfelt:

   - *Truly you’re a great friend.*
5. *Truly* can sound pretentious if you’re speaking casually. *Really* doesn’t have this problem:

   - This is fine: *This music really is loud!*
   - This is pretentious: *This music truly is loud!*

Some of this is especially obvious if you look at things statistically. I used [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) to find what [adjectives follow either word (up to four words ahead)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWg5.jpg):

[image: results of said collocation search]

The adjectives that follow *really* are simple, more colloquial words like *cute*, *hard*, and *nice*. The adjectives that follow *truly* look academic: *global*, *integrated*, and *multicultural*.